# Why do I get "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory" when joining a filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rgeo

I have a file I'm trying to open in a Rails application. For some reason Ruby is splitting the name of the file.

For example:

```
root = Rails.root
path = root.join('lib/tasks/filename.shp')
puts path
```

What is output is `/lib/tasks/filename/shp`.

Then I run the command:

```
factory = Region::GEOFACTORY
RGeo::Shapefile::Reader.open(path, :factory => factory) do |file|
```

I get the error message:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /lib/tasks/filename/.shp
```

It looks like the file has been split into `filename` and `.shp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
path = File.join(Rails.root, 'lib/tasks/filename.shp')
factory = Region::GEOFACTORY
RGeo::Shapefile::Reader.open(path, :factory => factory)
```